# javafx db load progress indicator

Tags: java, javafx-8

```
private Popup popupProgressIndicator;   
 public void showProgressIndicator(ScreensController myController) {
        if (popupProgressIndicator == null) {
            ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator(-1.0);
            indicator.setPrefHeight(200);
            indicator.setPrefWidth(200);
            indicator.setLayoutX(0);
            indicator.setLayoutY(0);
            popupProgressIndicator = new Popup();
            popupProgressIndicator.getContent().add(indicator);
        }
        if (!popupProgressIndicator.isShowing()) {
            popupProgressIndicator.show(primaryStage);
            popupProgressIndicator.centerOnScreen();
        }
        myController.setDisable(true);
    }
    public void hideProgressIndicator(ScreensController myController) {
        if (popupProgressIndicator.isShowing())
            popupProgressIndicator.hide();
        myController.setDisable(false);
    }
```

Hi I'm using above code for creating progress indicator in javafx app.
I want to show a progress indicator while loading data from db or saving data to db.

```java
@FXML
private void addDesignationSelect() {
    showProgressIndicator(myController);
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  // doing some heavy db process
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void succeeded() {
            hideProgressIndicator(myController);
        }
        @Override
        protected void failed() {
            super.failed();
            hideProgressIndicator(myController);
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

I have used Task for loading progress bar, but it is not showing the progress bar. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You call show your method `showProgressIndicator` before you start your Thread/Task. This is the reason why your window is not shown (or shown for a very short time)

You could open the progressBar and after `myController.setDisable(true);`, you can wait if the task returns a specific value (use `Task<Boolean>` for example).

The method `isDone()` will tell you when your Task has end and when to call `hideProgressIndicator`.

Another option would be to do the UI-Modifications from your Task itself, see the example here [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)